# Is there a asymptotic formula for product of primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

$$P(x)=\prod_{p\leq x}p$$

As you can see P(x) represents the product of primes which are not greater than x. Is there a asymptotic formula for this?

Comment: This is known as the [primorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), so you know what to Google. Incidentally, there is an asymptotic formula on that wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\vartheta$ is the [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function), we have the relationship

\begin{align*}
e^{\vartheta(x)} &= \operatorname{exp} \left(\sum_{p \le x} \log p\right) \\
&= \prod_{p \le x} p
\end{align*}

So [asymptotic bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Asymptotics_and_bounds) for the Chebyshev function carry over to the desired product.